# Web Scraper returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was making a Web Scraper with BeautifulSoup in Python but it returns None, how I can fix it?

This is where i **Scrape**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from hashlib import sha256
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
class QuoteScraper(object):
    def getData(self,link):
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find(class_='container')
        things = results.find_all('div', class_='quote')
        for thing in things:
            author = things.find('div', class_='author')
            print(author)
            text = things.find('span', class_='text')
            print(text)
            tags = things.find('div', class_='tags')
            print(tags)
            if None in (author, text, tags):
                continue
```

And here is where I call the Class & Function

```
soup = QuoteScraper()
print(soup.getData('http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
things = results.find_all('div', class_='quote')
for thing in things:
    author = things.find('div', class_='author')
    print(author)
    text = things.find('span', class_='text')
    print(text)
    tags = things.find('div', class_='tags')
    print(tags)
    if None in (author, text, tags):
        continue
```

you are doing `for thing in things:`, but never uses `thing` inside loop, is that intentional?

Comment: I don't know, it's my first project and I don't know much about Scraping, but if I replace {things} with {thing} stills returns None